# Magento 2 Paypal express question

Tags: magento2, paypal

In magento 1 paypal redirect message displayed on the page this way: 
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/payment/
"getRedirectMessage() ?>"
What function in magento 2 do the same? and which file is it in?

Answer (score 0):

Like M1, M2 doesn't have this type of method. You can go to **vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html**

Now check following code snippet:

```
<fieldset class="fieldset" data-bind='attr: {id: "payment_form_" + getCode()}'>
    <div class="payment-method-note">
        <!-- ko i18n: 'You will be redirected to the PayPal website.' --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Paypal/payment/express/billing-agreement' --><!-- /ko -->
</fieldset>
```

Now open **vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/paypal-express-abstract.js**

Following method is responsible for redirect:

```
/** Redirect to paypal */
continueToPayPal: function () {
    if (additionalValidators.validate()) {
        //update payment method information if additional data was changed
        this.selectPaymentMethod();
        setPaymentMethodAction(this.messageContainer).done(
            function () {
                customerData.invalidate(['cart']);
                $.mage.redirect(
                    window.checkoutConfig.payment.paypalExpress.redirectUrl[quote.paymentMethod().method]
                );
            }
        );

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any ideas about solving this? I Basically want to change the text and link to another page https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295698/change-paypal-payment-method-what-is-paypal-text-hyperlink-for-paypal-expre