# change Paypal Payment Method "What is Paypal?" text & hyperlink for Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, paypal, paypal-express

I'm trying to change the text and hyperlink for "What is Paypal?" for Paypal Express Checkout in the Payment step. Which file should i edit?

I changed the text of 'What is paypal?' in `vendor\magento\module-paypal\view\frontend\templates\payment\mark.pthml` but the changes does not show up on frontend after flush cache & recompile static content. Also, can't find the place to change the hyperlink.

mark.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
/**
 * Note: This mark is a requirement of PayPal
 * @var \Magento\Paypal\Block\Express\Form $block
 * @see \Magento\Paypal\Block\Express\Form
 */
$url = $block->escapeUrl($block->getPaymentAcceptanceMarkHref());
?>
<!-- PayPal Logo -->
<img src="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPaymentAcceptanceMarkSrc()) ?>"
     alt="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Acceptance Mark')) ?>" class="paypal icon"/>
<a href="<?= /* @noEscape */ $url ?>"
   onclick="javascript:window.open(
           '<?= /* @noEscape */ $url ?>',
           'olcwhatispaypal',
           'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, ,' +
           'left=0, top=0, width=400, height=350'
       ); return false;"
   class="action paypal about">
    <?php if ($block->getPaymentWhatIs()) {
        echo $block->escapeHtml(__($block->getPaymentWhatIs()));
} else {
        echo $block->escapeHtml(__('What is PayPal test test?'));
} ?>
</a>
<!-- PayPal Logo -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override this file in your theme to change "What is PayPal?" text on checkout page then...

> vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html

here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Paypal/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html

Here you can change text and run below command once.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you. In my case I have to use 'paypal-express-in-context.html' instead. Also, for editing the url, i have to copy '/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Config.php' to app folder and edit around line 1055.

Comment: You're welcome 