# How to add custom text after payment name radio button on checkout page?

Tags: magento2

I want add custom text after payment name on checkout page and different custom text on different stores

for ex :

- Cash on deliver               (Custom text 1)
- Paypal                        (Custom text 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this file for "Case on delivery" Payment method in your custom theme

> vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cashondelivery.html

here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_OfflinePayments/web/template/payment/caseondelivery.html

In this file you can add that label. Same thing you can do for PayPal as well. For PayPal you can check this for reference [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295698/change-paypal-payment-method-what-is-paypal-text-hyperlink-for-paypal-expre/295711#295711)

Here I'm adding custom label after **"Case on delivery"** Payment method in below example

Copy below file

> vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cashondelivery.html

here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_OfflinePayments/web/template/payment/caseondelivery.html

Content for this file is..

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span><span data-bind="text: getCustomLabel()"></span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I've added this line after `getTitle()`

```
<span data-bind="text: getCustomLabel()"></span>
```

and now we will override this `JS` file

> vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method.js

here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_OfflinePayments/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method.js

Content for this file is..

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_OfflinePayments/payment/cashondelivery'
        },

        getInstructions: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
        },

        getCustomLabel: function () {
            var websiteId = window.checkoutConfig.customerData.website_id;
            if(websiteId == 1){
                return 123;
            }else if(websiteId == 2){
                return 234;
            }
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Here I've created `getCustomLabel()` in this JS file and added condition based on `website_id` field.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I am using adyen extension which create payment methods like wechat pay and etc, I want custom text after those payment names.

Comment: Yes, you can override this html files in your theme and you can add label there as well [link](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-magento2/tree/develop/view/frontend/web/template/payment)

Comment: I would need a block also to get current store as I want different stores have different custom text.
can I do something like, I extend the main checkout phtml which loops the payment method name and add my custom text in if condition based on store_id which I will get by block ?

Comment: You can override JS file and you can create a function there to get label store wise

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. also have no idea of knockout JS.

Comment: Okay I'll send you one example within some time. So you can understand.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please review that @GauravHarsh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101505/discussion-between-gaurav-harsh-and-kishan-savaliya).